# Parse HTML table by column NOT row 

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

How do you parse an html table td by *column* and not by row (using DOMDocument / DOMXPath)?  Meaning parsing a td element based on the column of the table it is in, not which tr it is in?

Comment: What do you mean by `parsing`? Please show example input and what you hope to do with the data.

Comment: new DOMXPath(DOMDocument)->query("//td")->item(0)->getColumn()

Comment: I think you should "parse" the table by row, but sort each td (each column) into an array.  Then read through those arrays.  Otherwise, you'd have to read though each tr multiple times to read each column.

Comment: the td with rowspan/colspan greater than 1 is making that annoying

Comment: @SamAdams Well there's not a lot you can do about that. DOM parses the markup, it doesn't take how it would be displayed into account. If should be fairly easy to XPath for the `<tr>`s, loop the child `<td>`s and if they have a `colspan` reference that number of array indices together so they are accesible in the right key

Comment: @SamAdams: Why is `rowspan` causing a problem?

Comment: because they need to be remembered for future rows. having a getColumn would make this easier, if one row has only 1 td and another has 3

Answer (score 2):

HTML tables are grouped by rows, not columns. Your best bet it to iterate the rows and assign the rows to an appropriate array, synchronized by keys.

Example:

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML
<table id="target">
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);

$table = $document->getElementById("target");
$tr_list = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

$tr_count = 0;
$columns = array();
foreach ($tr_list as $tr) {
    /** @var $tr DOMElement */
    $td_list = $tr->getElementsByTagName("td");
    $tr_count++;
    $td_count = 0;
    foreach ($td_list as $td) {
        $columns[$tr_count][$td_count] = $td;
        $td_count++;
    }

}

print_r($columns);
```